# Accessing numbered UI elements in a loop

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface

I am coding a monopoly game in C# in a WPF project, and there are 40 spaces. In the C# code, I am able to make all the spaces; I have stored them in an array, Spaces[]. I am able to access space 3 with Spaces[2], but there are 40 visual elements on the XAML page, all spaces, and I'm not sure how to number them. I could call each of them SpaceX (Space0, Space1, Space2, etc.), but how would I access them? I can't just do

```
for (int i = 0; i < Spaces.Length; i++)
{
    window.(Space+i).Update();
}
```

because Space isn't a string. So how could I access different spaces in an array?

Comment: How about adding a property `Id` in your `Space` class and using that to uniquely number and identify a `Space`

Comment: How do you associate the visual elements in XAML with the data in the Spaces[] array? Are you storing the actual visual elements in the array, in which case `Spaces[i].Update()` should work? Or do you have some objects that you defined stored in Spaces[] and then have a bunch of visual elements in a XAML file that are not connected to Spaces[] array data at all? Please show some of your code.